# Magento 2: Blank static page on multiple web-server

Tags: magento-2.1

I have set up a Magento 2 website using 2 webservers.
When the request is served by the web server that holds the layout cache, the static page is fine.
But when the varnish is invalidated and the request goes to the secondary web server that doesn't have the layout cache, the static page is blank.
Where is this "layout" cache stored? our Magento is using Redis as well.

Comment: and how is redis cache configured?

Comment: i lost the magento 2.1 documentation for redis

Comment: ok i have configured the env.php to use redis as cache. but the blank page still appear sometime

Comment: i have to disable Layouts cache for now, we have varnish at front.

Comment: you have to upgrade to magento 2.3.2 and use single point for varnish and redis cache - NOT localhost

Comment: magento 2.1 supports redis for layout. but the problem came from something else.